# A problem in GCD to prove

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If gcd(a,b)=1, c|a and d|b then show that gcd(c,d)=1.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Hint: let $e=\gcd(c,d)$, then $e$ is a common divisor of $a$ and $b$ so...

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $\gcd(a,b)=1, c\mid a, d\mid b$. Then choose $x,y\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $ax+by=1$. Since $c\mid a, d\mid b$ choose $u,v\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $a=uc,b=dv$. Then $ucx+dvy=c(ux)+d(vy)=1$, whence $\gcd(c,d)=1$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a=kc,b=ld$  where $k,l$ are integers not equals to $0$.

$1=\gcd (a,b)=\gcd (kc,b)=\gcd (c,b)=\gcd (c,ld)=\gcd (c,d)$

**Why** these equality holds? Well, then you need to know the definition of $\gcd$